# eOS 5.1 shutdown/suspend not working

Tags: suspend, release-hera, command-line, shutdown

I've stumbled upon a problem where selecting shutdown or suspend from the power menu (little power icon in the top right corner) doesn't do the desired action.

Shutdown, and Restart, simply does nothing. I have to run "shutdown now" from the terminal to power down my PC.

Similarly, the Suspend option suspends the PC, but then immediately turns itself back on and shows the login screen. Running "systemctl suspend" returns no result.

I first noticed this behaviour last night. Only change that was made was installing TexMaker and a couple of addons for it.

Best that I can make out from looking at journalctl is that something in the network is blocking the actions.

Here is the dump.

```
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein sudo[5650]:  erasmus : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/erasmus ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl suspend
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein sudo[5650]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107977.3845] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein sudo[5650]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107977.3846] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd-logind[5495]: Error during inhibitor-delayed operation (already returned success to client): Unit suspend.target i
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107977.3878] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107977.3878] device (enp3s0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', s
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107977.4199] dhcp4 (enp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 5509
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107977.4199] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed bound -> done
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.11.78 on enp3s0.
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107977.4206] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.11.78.
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: Interface enp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::530b:3a1d:d71a:4f51 on enp3s0.
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::530b:3a1d:d71a:4f51.
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: Interface enp3s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107977.4212] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein dbus-daemon[801]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein dbus-daemon[801]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5660]: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (2 scripts)
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5660]: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107977.4376] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107977.4411] device (enp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', 
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein kernel: RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet r8169-300:00: attached PHY driver [RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-30
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5660]: req:2 'down' [enp3s0]: new request (2 scripts)
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5660]: req:2 'down' [enp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein pantheon-parent[808]: SessionManager.vala:92: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnect
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Service has no hold-off time, scheduling restart.
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd[1]: Stopped Login Service.
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein upowerd[997]: Could not acquire inhibitor lock: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconne
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein ModemManager[777]: <warn>  [sleep-monitor] inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipie
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd-logind[5681]: New seat seat0.
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd-logind[5681]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Power Button)
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd-logind[5681]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein gsd-sharing[1393]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein gsd-sharing[1393]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit vino-server.service n
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd-logind[5681]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event4 (SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD)
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd-logind[5681]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event7 (SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Keyboard)
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd-logind[5681]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event5 (SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD System Control)
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd-logind[5681]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event6 (SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Consumer Control)
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
Jan 15 19:06:17 kaptein systemd-logind[5681]: New session c2 of user erasmus.
Jan 15 19:06:19 kaptein ModemManager[777]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0': not supp
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2612] device (enp3s0): carrier: link connected
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2620] device (enp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2626] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1'
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2632] device (enp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (6676
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2634] device (enp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2635] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2637] device (enp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2640] device (enp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-ifac
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2642] dhcp4 (enp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2688] dhcp4 (enp3s0): dhclient started with pid 5692
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv6 with address fe80::530b:3a1d:d71a:4f51.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: New relevant interface enp3s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: Registering new address record for fe80::530b:3a1d:d71a:4f51 on enp3s0.*.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein dhclient[5692]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.11.78 on enp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x3476aaec)
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein dhclient[5692]: DHCPACK of 192.168.11.78 from 192.168.11.1
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2922] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   address 192.168.11.78
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   gateway 192.168.11.1
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   lease time 86400
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   nameserver '192.168.11.1'
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   nameserver '41.79.193.253'
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.11.78.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: New relevant interface enp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: Registering new address record for 192.168.11.78 on enp3s0.IPv4.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2940] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-if
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2945] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2946] device (enp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2947] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2976] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2978] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and D
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2985] device (enp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5660]: req:3 'up' [enp3s0]: new request (2 scripts)
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5660]: req:3 'up' [enp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein dhclient[5692]: bound to 192.168.11.78 -- renewal in 35272 seconds.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein systemd-resolved[762]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.11.1.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein gsd-sharing[1393]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein gsd-sharing[1393]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit vino-server.service n
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein CapNetAssist[5756]: DetectCaptivePortal script triggered
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5660]: <15>Jan 15 19:06:20 CapNetAssist: DetectCaptivePortal script triggered
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107992.8778] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein dbus-daemon[801]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein dbus-daemon[801]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5783]: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (2 scripts)
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5783]: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...

Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   gateway 192.168.11.1
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   lease time 86400
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   nameserver '192.168.11.1'
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   nameserver '41.79.193.253'
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.11.78.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: New relevant interface enp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: Registering new address record for 192.168.11.78 on enp3s0.IPv4.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2940] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-if
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2945] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2946] device (enp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2947] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2976] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2978] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and D
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2985] device (enp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5660]: req:3 'up' [enp3s0]: new request (2 scripts)
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5660]: req:3 'up' [enp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein dhclient[5692]: bound to 192.168.11.78 -- renewal in 35272 seconds.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein systemd-resolved[762]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.11.1.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein gsd-sharing[1393]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein gsd-sharing[1393]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit vino-server.service n
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein CapNetAssist[5756]: DetectCaptivePortal script triggered
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5660]: <15>Jan 15 19:06:20 CapNetAssist: DetectCaptivePortal script triggered
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107992.8778] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein dbus-daemon[801]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein dbus-daemon[801]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5783]: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (2 scripts)
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5783]: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...

Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   gateway 192.168.11.1
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   lease time 86400
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   nameserver '192.168.11.1'
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0):   nameserver '41.79.193.253'
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2923] dhcp4 (enp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.11.78.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: New relevant interface enp3s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein avahi-daemon[778]: Registering new address record for 192.168.11.78 on enp3s0.IPv4.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2940] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-if
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2945] device (enp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2946] device (enp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2947] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2976] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2978] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and D
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107980.2985] device (enp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5660]: req:3 'up' [enp3s0]: new request (2 scripts)
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5660]: req:3 'up' [enp3s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein dhclient[5692]: bound to 192.168.11.78 -- renewal in 35272 seconds.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein systemd-resolved[762]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.11.1.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein gsd-sharing[1393]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein gsd-sharing[1393]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit vino-server.service n
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein CapNetAssist[5756]: DetectCaptivePortal script triggered
Jan 15 19:06:20 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5660]: <15>Jan 15 19:06:20 CapNetAssist: DetectCaptivePortal script triggered
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein NetworkManager[806]: <info>  [1579107992.8778] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein dbus-daemon[801]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: gtk_widget_destroy: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein dbus-daemon[801]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein nm-applet[1532]: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5783]: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (2 scripts)
Jan 15 19:06:32 kaptein nm-dispatcher[5783]: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
```

Sorry for the wall of text.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue from the first day after upgraded to 5.1. Very annoying.

Comment: I have the same problem since the first day of installation. I'm sorry I can't help, but maybe by commenting here we can get a developer's attention.